# Why is mining not working/very slow in my testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, testnets

I created a testnet to allow faster smart contract testing (I don't want to use Truffle for now). My genesis file is

```
{
    "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    },
    "difficulty": "200000000",
    "gasLimit": "2100000",
    "alloc": {
        "7ca3a0da3345506f15c603eba011c8f354155ee9": { "balance": "400000000000000000000000000" }
    }
}
```

It is based on [this](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/network/test-networks.html) tutorial. I am starting geth with

```
geth --identity "test" --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpccorsdomain "*" --datadir ~/Desktop/private/datadir --port "30303" --nodiscover --rpcapi "db,eth,net,web3,personal" --networkid 1999 --mine --minerthreads=1 --etherbase=0x7ca3a0da3345506f15c603eba011c8f354155ee9 --unlock="0x7ca3a0da3345506f15c603eba011c8f354155ee9" console
```

I then created a new account and sent 1 ETH from `0x7ca3a0da3345506f15c603eba011c8f354155ee9` to my new account getting the following message as confirmation.

```
> INFO [07-31|22:46:56] New wallet appeared                      url=keystore:///Users/mcansado… status=Locked
INFO [07-31|22:46:56] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0x46b9c5c2a739a0e314d74b53158475b1686a196670d58a948332d3cdacf92d4b recipient=0x1918ced27804f6b83acf0587a81e9f56020620d1
INFO [07-31|22:47:29] Successfully sealed new block            number=2 hash=698a9b…8acfe8
INFO [07-31|22:47:29]  mined potential block                  number=2 hash=698a9b…8acfe8
INFO [07-31|22:47:30] Commit new mining work                   number=3 txs=1 uncles=0 elapsed=47.741ms
```

But the balance in the new account does not change. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey I dont exactly know the reason but i think the account is locked. When I use testnet and I create a new account the accounts are locked

Comment: It is not because I pass it the `--unlock` flag when I'm starting geth

Comment: when you create that account with geth new account it asks you for a password. You put that password in a txt file and that, like Richard said below you need to pass it with --password "your_password_file.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Your account is still locked.

> It is not because I pass it the --unlock flag when I'm starting geth

In the command you've used to start `geth`, you pass the `--unlock` flag with the account address you want to unlock. You don't, however, pass the `--password` option. This isn't a problem in itself, because not passing the `--password` flag just means you'll be prompted for the password. However, you also start in `console` mode, which seems to cause the password prompt to be lost.

The result is shown in the first line of you second snippit: the account is still locked.

```
INFO [07-31|22:46:56] New wallet...  url=keystore:///Users/mcansado… status=Locked
```